# Rails: Conflict Between Namespaced and Non-Namespaced Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, associations

I have two `Review` models. The first is namespaced as `Membership::Review` and the second is not namespaced, `Review`. When I make a call on the non-namespaced model, Rails tries to lookup the namespaced one, instead. For instance:

```
library.includes(:reviews)
```

Gets me this error:

```
Expected C:/sites/shelflives/app/models/membership/review.rb to define Review
```

In my `Library` model, the `Review` association is made properly:

```
has_one :review
```

Even if I explicitly specify the model, I get the same error:

```
has_one :review, :class_name => "Review"
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Did the error persists on `Membership::Review.new` command in rails console?

Comment: Yes, it persists with `Membership::Review.new` as well.

Comment: Did you added any extra path with `config.autoload_paths` for load your models in the application config?

Comment: I did: `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/')]`. This code autoloads subdirectors so I can better organize non-namespaced models.

Comment: Seems that is you problem, comment this line, restrart server and try in the console `Membership::Review.new`. You don't need to load sub-folders of models, they will load automaticaly by namespaces.

Comment: That does the trick. Unfortunately, not all of my models can be namespaced, and I'd prefer to keep them organized in subdirectories. Perhaps I can exclude the namespaced directories somehow, though. I'll look more into this.

Comment: I made an answer, let the people know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of errors occurs when you adding extra `config.autoload_paths` in the `application.rb` with sub-folders of models.

You don't need to do this. All models will load automaticaly through the namespaces. You just need to organize correct structure with sub-folders of namespaces.

If you using namespaces with models you can use generator like this:

```
rails g model membership/review
```

That will generate correct namespaced model and will save it to `membership` sub-folder .